# Appending the Parent folder Names to the Image File Names in Automator

Tags: terminal, command-line, automator, folders

I have this file structure. I wanted to use the image filename appended with the parent folder names.

**Before:**

```
├── ak
│   ├── adak
│   │   ├── Hello\ World456
│   │   ├── cup-printing
│   │   │   └── Tshirt-printing.jpg
│   │   ├── hello-\ world789
│   │   ├── hello-world79
│   │   └── tshirt\ printing
│   │       └── Tshirt-printing.jpg
│   ├── akhiok
│   │   ├── Hello\ World456
│   │   ├── cup-printing
│   │   │   └── Tshirt-printing.jpg
│   │   ├── hello-\ world789
│   │   ├── hello-world79
│   │   └── tshirt\ printing
│   │       └── Tshirt-printing.jpg
```

Here parent folder names are ak, adak.

Ak= state name
Adak = city name.

After it should be like this..

**After:**

```
├── ak
│   ├── adak
│   │   ├── Hello\ World456
│   │   ├── cup-printing
│   │   │   └── Tshirt-printing-adak-ak.jpg
│   │   ├── hello-\ world789
│   │   ├── hello-world79
│   │   └── tshirt\ printing
│   │       └── Tshirt-printing-adak-ak.jpg
│   ├── akhiok
│   │   ├── Hello\ World456
│   │   ├── cup-printing
│   │   │   └── Tshirt-printing-akhiok-ak.jpg
│   │   ├── hello-\ world789
│   │   ├── hello-world79
│   │   └── tshirt\ printing
│   │       └── Tshirt-printing-akhiok-ak.jpg
```

Bash command can help over here?

**In the Automator,**

I'm stuck at the finding the all the images of the file name having "tshirt" So I need to find the change the file name to their parent folder.

[image: file name rename with parent folder names]

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, and assuming the example holds true, then the *example* **`bash`** *code*, shown further below, should work.

The following **Automator** *workflow* uses the **Find Finder Items** *action*, as you have it, but then uses a **Run Shell Script** *action* directly after, as there doesn't seem to be a need for a **Set Value of Variable** *action* as shown in your OP.

On the **Run Shell Script** *action*, set **Pass input:** to **as arguments**, as shown in the image below.

Note that the `echo` *command* is just there to show what `mv` *command* would have been executed to rename the files had it not been there. So, after testing and seeing that the output if formed as wanted, remove the `echo` *command* and run the *workflow* again to actually rename the image files.

Replace the default *code* in the **Run Shell Script** *action* with the following *example* `bash` *code*:

```
for f in "$@"; do

    dn="$(dirname "$f")"
    fn="$(basename "$f")"
    city="$(awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-2)}'<<<"$f")"
    state="$(awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-3)}'<<<"$f")"

    echo mv "$f" "${dn}/${fn%.*}-${city}-${state}.${fn##*.}"

done
```

---

<sub>**Note:** The *example* **`bash`** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>

---

[image: Automator Workflow]

Comment: Thanks for the code, mate. While running the code, I get this error. couldn't posix_spawn error 7 Here is the screenshot of the error https://cl.ly/8ddb1e787f08

Comment: @Suresh Kumar G, The linked image in your comment is the same image that is in your OP, shows no error, and is meaningless to diagnose any issue. As you can plainly see in the image my **Automator** _workflow_, using the same settings as your **Find Finder Items** _action_ it returns the same filenames as in your `tree` view and can rename the files as you stated. Without seeing an image of your actual _workflow_ showing as mine shows, I cannot even begin to troubleshoot what's not working for you while it works for me.

Comment: Very fair point mate. I did show my workflow in the above comment. If you need any more information from my side let me know.